# jQuery $.removeAttr("selected") changes selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please take a look at the example: http://jsfiddle.net/HHDpK/1/

As you see the difference between two choosers is only the line

```
$("#chooser-1 .y").removeAttr("selected");
```

But as a result their states are different (especially in Chrome).
Am I missing anything, or it is a bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like internal bug of jQuery with attributes.

Note that in older versions, before `.prop()` was introduced in 1.6 version, it [works as expected](http://jsfiddle.net/HHDpK/4/).

In the newer versions, just use `.prop()` to deal with such properties of elements:

```
$("#chooser-1 .x").prop("selected", "selected");
$("#chooser-1 .y").removeProp("selected");
```

[jsFiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/HHDpK/3/).

More than that - using `.removeProp("selected")` on the element selected previously with `prop()` will cause the original selection to return instead of having nothing selected - ideal behavior.

Comment: Although it will work but prop() is not set selected attribute in html option element so I'm using both of them like this { .removeProp('selected').removeAttr('selected') } and { .prop('selected', 'selected').attr('selected', 'selected') }

Answer (score 3):

I found the above answer failed as well, I had to set the prop to false to get the selected items to not be.

```
$("#chooser-1 .x").prop("selected", false);
```

removeProp cause undesired effects such as not being able to re-select the options again.

I use jquery 1.6.2